# Moderne, gehobene Version von "Hof machen"

Tags: expression

Wie nennt man im **modernen** Deutsch den Vorgang, bei dem ein Mann mit originellen und durchdachten Aktionen die Aufmerksamkeit einer Frau auf sich lenkt? Der Ausdruck soll betonen, dass das Ganze mit Stil passiert.

Mir fällt *Hof machen* ein, aber der Ausdruck scheint ein wenig antiquiert. *Anbraten* ist dagegen zu grob. *Anmachen* wird verwendet, auch wenn das Ganze ohne Originalität gemacht wird.

Comment: Wenn es wirklich mit sehr viel Stil (und daher nach "alter Schule") passiert, finde ich "den Hofen machen" als Ausdruck auch in modernem Deutsch gar nicht so schlecht. Google findet mehr als eine Million Ergebnisse (ein Teil davon natürlich Wörterbücher usw.), der Ausdruck ist also durchaus noch in Gebrauch, nicht nur nach meinem persönlichem Sprachgefühl. "Umwerben" ist natürlich neutraler und moderner.

Comment: "den Hof machen" würde ich auf jeden Fall verwenden. Das würde gerade zum Ausdruck bringen, daß es mit Stil geschieht.

Comment: Jemandem `Avancen machen` wäre auch noch eine Möglichkeit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mir fallen dazu diese Ausdrücke ein:

> - jemanden umwerben
> - sich bemühen um jemanden
> - sich um jemandes Gunst/Liebe bemühen

*Diese Vorschläge sind dir wahrscheinlich zu informell:*

> - sich an jemanden heranmachen
> - jemanden anmachen

Comment: ich denke "umwerben" ist das, was "jmd. den Hof machen" am nächsten kommt